# Positioning absolute and relative elements with css

Tags: css, css-float

I tried to position html elements, but a failed badly. My html code is quiete simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>Header</<header>
    <div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            Sidebar
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <br/><br/>
            Content
            <br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the associated css file:

```
* {
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: center;
}

body{
    background-color: #888888;
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background-color: #ffff88;  
}

#content{
    background-color: #ff8888;  
}

#sidebar{
    background-color: #88ff88;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

footer{
    background-color: #8888ff;  
}
```

At the end the site should look like:
[image: Sketch of the side]

With a relative Header, footer and Content. The sidebar should have it's own scroll bar and should be behind footer and header, if they are in view.. Like here:
[image]

But the footer should always be on the bottom or "topsy".
The withe and transparent box should be clipping you can see currently in your browser.

When I tried to du this I got this mistakes:
[image]
The Footer is not at the bottom, when the Content is too small.

Or: The footer is not at the bottem, when I scrolled down.
[image]

Does someone know how to handle this issue with css?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the second figure. This one is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while a friend of mine helped me to get a nice solution, without JavaScript for the footer. Last one is difficult to realize if, the Content or the size of the page changes.
Here is the solution we found (with a simple JavaScript for the fixed sidebar).
the html-file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Footer Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script>
            function posSidebar(event){
                var b = document.getElementById('wBox').clientHeight;
                var w = window.innerHeight;
                var s = window.pageYOffset;
                document.getElementById('sidebar').style.top = Math.max(0, 30-s) + "px";
                document.getElementById('sidebar').style.bottom = Math.max(w-b+s-0,0) + "px";
            }
            window.onscroll = posSidebar;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wBox">
            <header>
                <p>Header</p>
            </header>
            <div id="body">
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <p id="log">Sidebar</p><p id="log1">Sidebar</p><p id="log2">Sidebar</p><p id="log3">Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p>
                    <p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p>
                    <p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p>
                    <p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p>
                    <p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p>
                    <p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p><p>Sidebar</p>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the css-file:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #999;
}


div#wBox{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    position: relative;
}

footer{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #9f9;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f99;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff9;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

header{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #99f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle :**[UPDATED 2]**

**http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/g5Uk3/1/**

**css**

```
.header, .footer {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:200;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color: #ffff88;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #8888ff;
}
.content {
    width:80%;
    margin-left:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #ff8888;
    color:white;
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #88ff88;
    color:white;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>Side bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

To keep footer at bottom when content is less : 
http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/g5Uk3/2/

add this jQuery Script -

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(function () {
        var bht = $('body').height();
        var wht = $(window).height();
        if (bht < wht) {
            $('.footer').css("bottom", "0px");
        }
    });
});
</sctipt>
```

Comment: Thx, but the footer and the header should not be fixed. They should scroll like the #content. Similar to this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api

Comment: Very nice. How can the sidebar get the remaining space at the left side between (and not under) the footer and header? The footer is not at the bottom, if the content is too small :(

Comment: is it fine with you to include a small js?

Comment: Ok. But how to make the border of the sidebar touches the footer and the Header? As in figure 1 and 2? so the sidebar has a flexible height?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float value:

```
<header>Header</<header>
    <div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            Sidebar
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <br/><br/>
            Content
            <br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />
    <footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

For #sidebar you should add

```
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 80px;
```

(the top value should be based on the header's height)

Similarly to #footer

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
```

This should help you achieve what you are looking for.
Let me know if this helped, or not, and I'll try to assist in this.

Comment: Here I have Problem two: When I scroll down. The footer is in the middle of the Content. And the top value is based on the containing div and Looks like it should be 0 to touch the header.